# Форматировать строку с тегами HTML в соответствующий текст

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

есть строка: `<p><em><strong>Компания </strong></em>Рога и Копыта <strong>&quot;Начальник &quot;</strong></p> <p><strong>Задачи начальника:</strong><li> итд`
Как мне легко и красиво заменить все HTML теги на нужные сущности для корректного отображения в txt файле?
больше всего интересует замена `<p>` и `<li>` на перенос строки, замена кавычек `&quot;`. Остальное если возможно, то будет супер.
Можно сделать replace, но мне кажется это костыль, возможно есть какой то модуль который сделает все красиво

Comment: Ну тут лучше `replace` ничего нет, можно еще регуляркой, но это то же самое

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694669/15035314

Comment: @АлексейР то что надо, спасибо! Подскажи пожалуйста, soup.get_text('\n') вывел текст с переносами, но местами сделал их чрезмерно много (где должен быть один перенос- сделал два). Как убрать пустые строки из полученного текста?

Comment: Можно регуляркой удалить пустые строки